# Python selenium can't do if statement on 2 web elements same place different with id

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

There are 2 div id's `phone_number_1-42` and `contact_seller_1-42` in random order.

I'm trying to do simple if but couldn't find anything that works.

```
phone_reveal_1 = driver.find_element_by_id('phone_number_0')  
contact_seller_1= driver.find_element_by_id('contact_seller_0')
if phone_reveal_1:
else:
    contact_seller_1.click()
```

I tried to use `isEnabled` ,`.size() != 0`,`>0`,`None` but it won't click.
any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 ways to check whether element present or not. You should go with `find_elements` instead of `find_element`.

**`findElement`** method is used to access a single web element on a page. It returns the first matching element. It throws a `NoSuchElementException` exception when it fails to find If the element.

**`findElements`** method returns the list of all matching elements. the findElements method returns  an empty list when the element is not available or doesn’t exist on the page. It doesn’t throw `NoSuchElementException`.

Using `if` `else`:

```
phone_reveal_1 = driver.find_elements_by_id('phone_number_0')
contact_seller_1 = driver.find_elements_by_id('contact_seller_0')
if len(phone_reveal_1) > 0:
    phone_reveal_1[0].click()
elif len(contact_seller_1) > 0:
    contact_seller_1[0].click()
else:
    print("both element are not there")
```

Using `try` `except`:

```
try:
    driver.find_element_by_id('phone_number_0').click()
except NoSuchElementException:
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_id('contact_seller_0').click()
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print("both element are not there")
```

Answer (score 0):

thats worked for me thank you!

if phone_reveal_1.is_displayed():
phone_reveal_1.click()
elif contact_seller_1.is_displayed:
contact_seller_1.click()
else: